# MS AJAX HTMLEditor - Customize the Toolbars

Tags: c#, ajax, html-editor

I'm using the MS AJAX HTMLEditor component on a web site. However, I want to be able to customize the toolbars that are available to users. From what I've read, it seems to be handled with CSS but the documentation doesn't really provide exact customization code. I'd like my editor to look exactly like the one at: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/OtherSamples/LiteNoBottom.aspx

But I can't find the right combination of CSS to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer to this. Its actually not related to CSS at all, you have to override the control and then add the buttons you want.

Comment: Can you provide further details, or a link to them?